# How to list all days in a given month using Jodatime

Tags: java, jodatime

I am looking for a way to list all days of a given month using Jodatime. 
It would be great to have concrete code sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I couldn't find answer to this question, I post the code here so someone can find use of it:

```
// set your own print format here
private static final DateTimeFormatter DF=DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");

    private List<String> createMonthLabels(LocalDate month) {
    // add labels
    List<String> daysInMonthLabels = new ArrayList<String>();
    LocalDate firstDay = month.withDayOfMonth(1);
    LocalDate nextMonthFirstDay = firstDay.plusMonths(1);
    while (firstDay.isBefore(nextMonthFirstDay)) {
        daysInMonthLabels.add(DF.print(firstDay));
        firstDay = firstDay.plusDays(1);
    }

    return daysInMonthLabels;
}
```

Comment: Don't use datetime/datemidnight (they are precise points in time) when  you are meaning just dates, that's conceptually wrong. Replace DateMidnight/DateTime by `LocalDate`, and your answer is fine.